# How to disable option+f1 shortcut?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, shortcut

MacOS Sierra 10.12.6
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports).

When I press <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>, a display system preferences window comes up.

It conflicts with my application specific shortcut.

How can I disable <kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> triggering display settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's not actually on  <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>F1</kbd> , it's on the "special functions" keys, so it's triggered by the  symbol rather than the actual F-Key.

To get the 'true' F-key you could either press  <kbd>Fn</kbd>   <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>F1</kbd>  or alternatively swap all your F-key Functionality in System Prefs > Keyboard > Keyboard

[image]

<sup>sorry for the emoji, couldn't find anything better ;-)</sup>